# If two matrices are row equivalent, will there transpose be row equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let's suppose I have two matrices A and B of same dimensions. Given is A and B are row equivalent. Will transpose (A) be row equivalent to transpose (B)? If yes then prove it.

Comment: Clearly, $A^T$ and $B^T$ are column equivalent, so the question is equivalent to asking whether row equivalence is equivalent to column equivalence.

Comment: The hint would be: use the definition of "row equivalent"